# How to Automatically Populate a Rolling Table From a Single Cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to build an update log for our Windows Systems so we can keep track of when the computers were updated, including a history of previous update dates. That way we can report these dates to our board.

Is it possible to pull the date from one cell to populate the table while automatically going down the column of another table so I don't have to input all of the dates by hand as the updates roll-out?

[image: DateTable]

I want to have the dates I enter into this table be also entered into a second table which; starting from the top row, automatically imports the date contents of the cell from the first table.

[image: LogTable]

Comment: The example is not very clear.

Comment: Are you trying to automatically populate your 1st screenshot, or your 2nd screenshot? I agree, this example is not clear.

Comment: I apologize for not being particularly clear, the question I have is a bit hard to put into words. I'm trying to populate the 2nd screenshot's table. I want to be able to have the date pulled from the first table and appended to the 2nd screenshot's table.

Comment: I suggest using a different approach by creating a table for the raw data containing 2 columns named `Computer Name` and `Date Updated` in which a new row is added each time a computer is updated. You could then create the two tables in the screenshots by using formulas and/or pivot tables and/or Power Query. This way you have more flexibility if you want to later change the format of the tables. You can also easily add new columns if you later decide to include more information concerning each update.